# how can threshold error to avoid in large list (over 200k items) of sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a very large list containing more than 200 000 of records, however I fetched record by increasing view threshold level. But all these make application very slow, so I am looking efficient and standard solution to fetch item from large list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pagination in your fecthes and make sure if you are filtering to setup proper indexes in your columns

Have a look at this article on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.listitemcollectionposition.aspx

This snippet will iterate your list in batches of 10:

```
using (SPWeb oWebsiteRoot = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb)
{
    SPList oList = oWebsiteRoot.Lists["Announcements"];
    SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
    oQuery.RowLimit = 10;    oQuery.Query = "<OrderBy Override=\"TRUE\">" +  
       "<FieldRef Name=\"FileLeafRef\" /></OrderBy>";
    int intIndex = 1;

    do
    {
        Response.Write("<BR>Page: " + intIndex + "<BR>");
        SPListItemCollection collListItems = oList.GetItems(oQuery);

        foreach(SPListItem oListItem in collListItems)
        {
            Response.Write(SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oListItem["Title"]) + 
              "<BR>");
        }
        oQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = 
          collListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition;
        intIndex++;
    } while(oQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition != null);
}
```